# Scope model not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create my own virtual scroll and I am faced with a problem. When my scroll reaches the end of the window, the `handlescroll()` function is executed, which adds data to `$scope.model`. I believe that `$scope` should update itself without additional `$scope.$apply()`. But even adding `$scope.$apply()` doesn't help.

Look at my plnkr: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Ku9l1HI0DstTGw6e

Comment: 1) if you check your console, there are errors and warnings.
2) where is `handlescroll` called? I could only find the declaration

Comment: `element.on('scroll')` is getting called in `directive.js` once you reach the bottom of the page. `$controller.handleScroll` is never triggered.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve with the `handlescroll` function. It is not referenced anywhere, hence it is never called. It has nothing to do with `$scopr.$apply()`

Comment: @J.Do , sorry, I redid the plankr to the original form in which there was no update. Please, check plnkr.

Comment: I use function handlescroll for add the data to $controller.model.rows. Data has been added but the view is not updated. But right at the beginning I assign controler.model to scope.model. In theory, when the controller.model is changed, the scope model changes.

Answer (score 0):

Please see edited plunker:

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/4OiS8PXjCAsipx1Y

Changes are in `controllers.js` and `index.html`. I've created a new variable called `$scope.rowList` and set the `$controller.model.rows` to it and changed the `ng-repeat` to use the `$scope.rowList`.

Comment: Yes, I tried to use `$scope` properties for arrays that change and it works, but is there any way to do this with the `$controller.array = []` syntax(how is it done in my plnker) and pass it to html along with `controllerAs` syntax.